# BLOB not storing utf-8 (Chinese) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE account_data (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    data BLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

However MySQL is not storing it as Chinese, but some garbage values
like «å«¢ å æææ æ­¶ç·è
I checked everywhere and it says CHARSET must be utf8, which is my case
The MySql version I am using is 5.6.14.

I Tried

```
ALTER TABLE account_data MODIFY data BLOB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

but for some reason, MySQL is giving syntax error for BLOB.

If I do

```
insert into account_data (id
            ,data)
        VALUES
            (5952638508182497,

"123456偟 滭滹漇 嶕憱撏 齞齝囃 熤熡"

            );
```

and check TEXT in Viewer in MySQL workbench, I can see 123456 but for Chinese I am seeing garbage.

Thanks

Comment: `BLOB` *is* binary garbage, how/when/where do you expect this to be shown as Chinese characters? How exactly are you inserting the data?

Comment: I am using MyBatis to insert and select, I will show the data as JSON. For English it is working quite well, only for Chinese I am facing the issue.

Comment: Show some concrete code examples.

Comment: That pretty much simply means your viewer is not interpreting the binary data in the right encoding (because it's just meaningless binary to it). Doesn't mean MySQL stores it incorrectly or anything.

Comment: But when i do Select statement and map it to a POJO and convert to JSON, for english it works well but for Chinese it shows garbage. What should I do? And Viewer is interpreting English text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101174/discussion-between-yogi-and-deceze).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set char set of DB and also column.

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: I tried this ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> BLOB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; but for some reason MySQL is giving syntax error for BLOB.

Comment: BLOB is binary type, char set only apply for text field. For BLOB, the encode issue may be from the way to write and read the BLOB file in the code.

Answer (score 0):

For Chinese, you want `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, and optionally some `COLLATION` starting with `utf8mb4_`, the default is probably fine.

`BLOB` should work as you described it, but probably the insertion connection and the reading connection were configured differently.  You mentioned Workbench; what charset is set up in it?  Was that used for both reading and writing?

The sample gibberish you provided (which does not map correctly into any Chinese) *looks* like Mojibake, which is usually caused by having `latin1` established for the connection.  (This was the old default.)

You mentioned 5.6.14; what that used for both inserting and selecting?